# React image not rendering - /Capture.PNG which falls outside of the project src/ directory. Relative imports outside of src/ are not supported

Tags: reactjs, reactstrap

I am attempting to render an image in React-Strap.

I have tried importing the image from an images folder as pictured below.

**folder set up**

[image]

I have also tried putting the image directly into the source folder and then utilizing it in the code as pictured below.

**folder set up**

[image]

This is the actual error I am getting:

**Actual Error**

[image]

I have tried the following image tags in my code:

**Attempted Code**

[image]

Each time I get an error that says the image falls outside of the project and that relative imports outside of the source folder are not supported.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is ended up working for me.

1. [image: First, import the image. Even though the image file was in the same path as the .js file, I still had to use the two dots before the forward slash.]
2. [image: Second utilize the image as below with the named import within the curly braces.]

Answer (score 1):

You have to add `.` before your paths:

Examples: `./Photo.png` <- your working file and photo are in the same folder

`./Directory/Photo.png` <- the photo is in a folder that is at the same deep with your current working folder

`../Directory/Photo.png` <- here you go one folder back and then in the folder where photo is

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to import image at the top, like this:

import img from "./Capture.png" ( if image is in the same folder as your js file).

And then in the code return like this:

`<img src={img} />`

This should work.